# How can I remove a workspace folder from the Source Control View?

Tags: visual-studio-code, repository, workspace

I am currently in the process of following a course to learn Python. For that, I have created a repository to sync the stuff via github. In addition I can keep practicing git.

I now started a side-project. For which I set up a new repository.
I want to quickly access all the data from the first repository, so I added the folder to my workspace.
Unfortunately, it also adds that first repo to the Source Control.
[PythonKurs Repo is unwanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnNsV.png)

I can choose "Close Repository" and it removes the unwanted repo.
[Temporarily removed Repo from Source Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHMoU.png)
But as soon as I close VSC and open it, the unwanted repo is back.

Is there any ways to "permanently" remove that Workspace folder from the Source Control, **for this Workspace only**? Ofc I want to keep the .git history for that course folder.

Comment: how did you add the folder to your workspace? Are you using multi-root workspaces?

Comment: I added the folder via "File ->Add Folder to Workspace". So from quickly checking the description on the website, this qualifies as a multi-root workspace.
Is there another way I can add my other folder so I can quickly access the files, without the need to open a 2nd VSC Window?